# ServerSocket how to receive multiple files

Tags: java, java-8, serversocket

I have studies project. I my teacherd don't want to tell me how to solve problem with receive multiple files. I know I need to use function getInputStream() but I don't know how to split those files in this inputStream object. I need to split this inputStream beacuse I need to save each file in folder.

Thank you for your help and for explaining this problem to me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you probably need a transmission protocol like HTTP or FTP. But if you don't want something that high level, what you can do is tar and then gzip your files, which is what people did on unix back in the day. Tar is still basically a transmission protocol, but maybe not as heavyweight as HTTP or FTP

Comment: I use HTTP by ServerSocket

Comment: @MateuszSobczak Okay then you either need to use existing Servlet framework and Apache Tomcat, or parse the HTTP request yourself.

Comment: I can't use tomact. I can use only java objects

Comment: @MateuszSobczak then I've given you all the help I can give. Honestly, this project / assignment where you are expected to reinvent the wheel is not a productive learning exercise

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your instructor wants you to create a protocol. The reason you will need a protocol is that if you send multiple files across the same socket you wont know when one file stops and another begins. To simplify the problem I will use a simple chat application as example, but the same will apply to files.

Lets say you have a chat app which has only 2 users (one server to client). Each user can send a message of any length. Lets say User1 wants to send User2 the following messages (each line is one message)

```
Hello User
How are you doing today?
```

If you send each of those raw messages across the socket you would likely get
`Hello UserHow are you doing today?`. Now how do you know where one message started and another stopped?

Simple solution is to send something before each message stating a length of characters in the upcoming message, so your message might be

```
11Hello User24How are you doing today?
```

So the end user knows that I read an int which tells me `<length>`, then read `<length>` characters to get a full message.

---

Now thats a pretty basic example and not super great. Lets look at a simple packet format I have seen used in a video game:

```
Field Name   Field Type   Notes
Length       VarInt       Length of packet data + length of the packet ID
Packet ID    VarInt 
Data         Byte Array   Depends on the connection state and packet ID, see the sections below
```

This is the basic format all information between the client and server uses. A length of data to be read, a packet type followed by its data for that packet type.

---

For your use case you likely need something similar, some sort of meta data about the bytes you are sending. EG: Length of file, file name.

I would start by looking at the [DataInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) class for easily reading primitive data types.